# Getting foreground window size wrong all the time

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, c#-4.0, winforms-interop

I am writing a program on c# that implements mouse and keyboard hooks and once a specified key clicked it will go and grab foreground window and save it's x,y, height and width into xml file.

I am not sure what is wrong, but I keep getting wrong sizes and wrong parameters.

I would appreciate a help on this one as I been struggling for two days with it now.

Bellow is relevant code.

Standard declarations:

```
//rectangle for the windows size
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int Left;
            public int Top;
            public int Right;
            public int Bottom;
        }


        //win API
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        [DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT Rect);
```

And the relevant code itself

```
void mouseHook_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.handle = GetForegroundWindow();   
        }

        #region keyboard pressed
        void keyboardHook_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {            
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F9) //if slot selected
            {
                RECT Rect = new RECT();
                SetForegroundWindow(this.handle);
                //this.handle = GetForegroundWindow();    
                GetWindowRect(this.handle, ref Rect);

                Grid newSlot = new Grid();
                newSlot.topX = Rect.Top;
                newSlot.topY = Rect.Left;
                newSlot.width = Rect.Right - Rect.Left;
                newSlot.height = Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top;

                layoutGrid.Add(newSlot);
                lbl_slots.Text = layoutGrid.Count().ToString();
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F10) //if main stack slot selected
            {
                RECT Rect = new RECT();
                SetForegroundWindow(handle);
                GetWindowRect(GetForegroundWindow(), ref Rect);    
                for (int i = 0; i < layoutGrid.Count(); i++) //selecting slot for main stack
                {
                    layoutGrid[i].slot_number = i + 1; //setting slots numbers
                    if (layoutGrid[i].topX != Rect.Top && layoutGrid[i].topY != Rect.Left)
                        layoutGrid[i].is_stack = false;
                    else
                    {
                        layoutGrid[i].is_stack = true;
                        lbl_stackSlot.Text = (i + 1).ToString();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**EDIT:**
I have tried to use both public struct RECT and Rectangle, the values with RECT I receive seems to be random, I mean left and top and height and width, sometimes it will find the proper points , but sometimes it seems completely random ones. The values I receive with Rectangle seems to have proper left and top but return wrong height and width.

Comment: In what way are the returned values wrong? Why do you not check for errors?

Comment: It just returns wrong values, as weird as it sounds. I am not sure how it can be checked for the errors, I simply get wrong values.

Comment: Give us something more than that. Are the values all zero? Are they all off by 2 or 3? Are they all -666? Help us.

Comment: I added edit to bottom of my thread.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution. Figured out will post it here if anyone ever runs into same problem.

I ended up using GetWindowInfo instead of GetWindowRect and it is worked like charm.

Took the code example from and article I found online http://kenneththorman.blogspot.com/2010/08/c-net-active-windows-size-helper.html

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Using `System.Drawing.Rectangle` is incorrect. The fields do not match. Your definition of `RECT` is correct.

I'm guessing a little, but your problem could be related to the comment at the bottom of the [`GetWindowRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633519%28VS.85%29.aspx) MSDN topic.

> Apps under Vista that are not linked with WINVER=6 will receive a misleading set of values here, that do not account for the extra padding of "glass" pixels Vista Aero applies to the window. This appears to happen even in Aero Basic (without Glass) to retain sizing consistency. The workaround (if you don't want to set WINVER=6) seems to be to dynamically bind to dwmapi.dll and use GetProcAddress() to obtain the DwmGetWindowAttribute() function, and call it with the DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS argument to request the genuine window frame dimensions.

Comment: I am using Win7, but I guess it is same as Vista in that regard. Would you mind to provide an example code (just something I can look on and get the idea) or link to some example. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I think the onus is on you to first of all check whether this is a plausible explanation. I don't want to waste my time if "returns wrong values" turns out to be something else. Also, you should be able  to p/invoke to this API quite easily.

Comment: You right! I just turned aero off and switched to basic window theme that looks like old XP, and the problem is still there. I guess it is somewhere in my code.